# Access pgbouncer instance for redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, pgbouncer

I am using pgbouncer on redshift cluster. When I use pgbouncer on Postgres I can login into pgbouncer instance using `psql -h localhost -p xxxx pgbouncer`.

But how do I login into pgbouncer setup for redshift? pgbouncer is running on an ec2 instance whereas reshift is managed by aws.

I tried accessing psql using both localhost (where pgbouncer is running) and redshift endpoint. Any idea on how to access pgbouncer instance, which is setup for redshift?

```
[ec2-user@xxxx ~]$ psql -h localhost -p 5439 -U admin pgbouncer
psql: ERROR:  not allowed
ERROR:  not allowed
[ec2-user@xxxx pgbouncer]$ psql -h xxxxxxxx.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U admin pgbouncer
Password for user admin:
psql: FATAL:  database "pgbouncer" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to login using

```
$ psql -h pgbouncerhost -p 5439 -U master pgbouncer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the pgbouncer database on redshift.

When the redshift cluster was created, a single database was also created (specified), you can find this by looking at the AWS console.

You can then log in to that database, using PSQL if you wish.

```
psql -h xxxxxxxx.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U admin your-redshift-db
```

from there you can create the pgbouncer database.

```
create database pgbouncer;
```

I suggest you use pgbouncer-rr which has more redshift features. 
https://github.com/awslabs/pgbouncer-rr-patch

Comment: Thanks Jon, I should have been more clear. Yes I am using pgbouncer-rr and did create pgbouncer database as you mentioned. But this does not show the commands and options which show up when connecting to pgbouncer server on postgresql db. For example - show clients, show connections etc. Does pgbouncer instance not exists when its created for redshift using pgbouncer and pgbouncer-rr-patch? Please let me know if there is any way to access it to monitor the connections.

Comment: Do the queries work/run on redshift when routed that way?

Comment: Yes the queries get executed on Redshift cluster, here is the link of the pgbouncer for redshift. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/query-routing-and-rewrite-introducing-pgbouncer-rr-for-amazon-redshift-and-postgresql/

Comment: No, I know how it works! I was asking whether in your setup, does anything run on the redshift cluster when you use pgbouncer-rr?